# How to show a widget on touch with flutter?

Tags: flutter

is there a way to make a widget (ex. a button) visible only on touch?
I want to make a way to show the edit button on the image just when image is touched.

```
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/profileimg/empty.jpg',
                  width: 110.0,
                  height: 110.0,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: -2,
                  left: 5,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    
              child: Text('Edit...'),
              onPressed: null,
            ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Thank you.

Comment: by **hover** you mean when for example user touch and drag it to left or right?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Touch on the image.

Comment: The title of this question should be changed, as it has nothing to do with hover, but rather is about the tap gesture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place this code inside your `StatefulWidget` widget:

```
  bool showEditButton = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: ()=>setState(()=>showEditButton = true),
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/profileimg/empty.jpg',
            width: 110.0,
            height: 110.0,
          ),
        ),
        if(showEditButton)
        Positioned(
          bottom: -2,
          left: 5,
          child: RaisedButton(

            child: Text('Edit...'),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```